# Google Chrome display different pages after go back

Tags: wordpress, google-chrome, diff, back

I have Wordpress project with advert banners. The banners are just pictures `<img src="path">` encapsulated by `<a href="target">`. Nothing special... Now when we are testing the web, we have found that when there is opened article detail and user click on banner and then press back button (or go back in any other way) the chrome display homepage of our web (not article detail). Actually, sometime display article detail, but not the article where I was before clicking on banner.

I have tried restart browser/computer, open URL in any other computer and the problem is only when I use Google Chrome. Exactly v.42.0.2311.152.

Do anyone have any experience with that?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the problem. There was tracking clicks by Google Analytics:

`<a href="target" onclick="return _ga_send()">`

in the `_ga_send` method was redirecting by Javascript

`window.location.replace("target");`

It replace the current location and if you go back (from AD), browser remember the page before you get on.

The solution is:

`window.location.href = "target";`